# Is it possible to trip only specific lines in google sheet importhtml function

Tags: google-sheets, importhtml

I am trying to fetch market price from a website using importhtml & It comes in rows & columns,

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://www.moneycontrol.com/commodity/gold-price.html", "table", 3)
```

Answer for the same is multiple columns

I am able to edit it even further using the below.

```
=INDEX(IMPORTHTML("https://www.moneycontrol.com/commodity/gold-price.html", "table", 3), 1, 1)
```

But the result of the above is this in one single cell.

"Sep 15, 15:06
49814.00*-204.00 (-0.41%)*"

Is it possible to get only `49816`?

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `regexextract()`, like this:

```
=value( 
  regexextract( 
    importhtml("https://www.moneycontrol.com/commodity/gold-price.html", "table", 3), 
    ":\d+\s+(\d+)" 
  ) 
)
```

Comment: Thank you, that resolved my issue.

Comment: Can you tell me how can I scrap the LTP from this page moneycontrol.com/india/stockpricequote/finance-investment/… Unfortunately google finance doesn't track Gold SGB & I am unable to track this using google finance

Comment: Ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741). Post a [new question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) instead.